# "electron-rebuild" breaks running "react-scripts test" i.e. Jest

Tags: jestjs, electron, create-react-app, react-scripts, electron-rebuild

`react-scripts test` runs on Node and my app runs on Electron's compiled version of Node.

Thus I get the classic error:

```
 The module '.../better_sqlite3.node'
    was compiled against a different Node.js version using
    NODE_MODULE_VERSION 103. This version of Node.js requires
    NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
    the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

This has been partly addressed here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

**But here is the problem**: If I run `npm rebuild`, `react-scripts test` starts working but I can't run my app. If I run `electron-rebuild`, my app starts up but `react-scripts test` stops working.

It's a pain to have to keep running these 2 different commands based on what I am trying to do.

How do people fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this workaround:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm rebuild && react-scripts test",
    "run": "electron-rebuild && electron .",
  }
```